# WMS filter by Date

Tags: leaflet, cql, geoserver, wms

I have a WMS layer getting served from Geoserver. The layer exposes a date property that is stored in the database as a Date type. I would like to filter the layer by date range. For example: cql_filter=date>2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z.

I am having a difficult time getting this to work and an unable to find any working examples.

Does any one have a working CQL date range example? Or Filter date range examples?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: which database are your data in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has some examples.

[Intro to CQL](http://svemir.co/2012/08/16/introduction-to-cql-and-geoserver-implementation/)

One thing that I have run into with CQL is the case sensitivity and field naming.  In your example you reference `date` as a field.  Maybe `date` is a reserved word?  Try bumping up your logging in geoserver and check for errors or see what SQL gets generated. Double check the field name in the layer definition.

Comment: The given link *Intro to CQL* returns 404

Answer (score 3):

My question asked for some working examples and Jason's answer provided just that.

Below are some working examples that filter a WMS by Date with leaflet.

A CQL example

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://myWMSUrl', {
  layers: 'namespace:layer',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.1.1',
  cql_filter: 'date AFTER 2015-07-01T00:00:00Z AND date BEFORE 2015-07-01T00:00:00Z'
});
```

A Filter XML example

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://myWMSUrl', {
  layers: 'namespace:layer',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.1.1',
  filter: '<PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>date</PropertyName><Function name="dateParse"><Literal>yyyy-MM-dd</Literal><Literal>2015-07-01</Literal><Function></PropertyIsGreaterThan>'
});
```

Comment: if you want inclusive dates:  'date BETWEEN 2015-07-01T00:00:00Z AND 2015-07-01T00:00:00Z'